# ESAPI Class Not Found Error on Glassfish

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, owasp, esapi

I've just started trying to use the OWASP ESAPI class in a RESTFul application I am building.

I installed the esapi stuff following their instructions on the website using svn, which didn't work.

I then included the jar file I needed manually by configuring the buildpath and adding it as an external JAR file. It then appeared in the Java Resources\Libraries folder  and everything compiled and published fine. I am using glassfish with eclipse.

I don't understand how if I am able to compile the code, glassfish doesn't have the class? Do I need to install the jar on the server?

The relevant code is:

```
import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;

String clean = rs.getString(column_name); //saving column data to temp variable
clean = ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(clean); //decoding data 
clean = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(clean); //encoding data
```

Here is the error it is throwing:

```
2015-06-29T20:50:16.244+0100|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[Jersey Web     Application]: Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/owasp/esapi/ESAPI
    at com.pododdle.util.ToJSON.toJSONArray(ToJSON.java:60)
    at com.pododdle.dao.MySQL.runDBQuery(MySQL.java:55)
    at com.pododdle.service.CategoryService.getAllCategories(CategoryService.java:10)
    at com.pododdle.resources.CategoryResource.getCategories(CategoryResource.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Glassfish, but in tomcat it'll either get compiled into your warfile or you drop it in the <tomcat>/lib directory.

Comment: I tried putting the .jar for ESAPI in the glassfish lib directory but that did not work, gave the same error. Is there anyway adding it in the classpath or something might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by adding the esapi.properties file to the WEB-INF/classes folder. (I had to create this classes folder)

The esapi.properties file can be found in the "configuration" folder of the esapi 1.4.4 installation directory.

You need to restart your webserver, i think, and then it runs smoothly.

Extremely annoying bug, and I have no idea why this works, but hey!

Comment: Esapi 1.4.4?  That is horribly outdated!  The most recent version is 2.1 and even that one is stale:  no releases have been published since 2013.  What are your security requirements?

Comment: Just doing a simple rest website - quite new to the security aspect. Just trying to prevent sql injection in my database. Do you recommend using something else?

Comment: For SQL injection, for whatever you're using for your ORM layer, just make sure you're always using parameterized queries.  Never concatenate user input into a query.  ESAPI can help this to a certain extent--there are codecs to escape strings for SQL, but its only there for fast remediation of legacy code that needs to be refactored.  Also--always store raw data:  don't escape for HTML before persisting.  Always escape when sending data into another context (browser, JSON, etc...)